# does the SecurityTokenValidated callback automatically validate the token using Owin Middleware

Tags: c#, azure, owin, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I am using Azure Ad and have setup my `Startup.Auth.cs` file as follows
I am able to connect to and use Azure, Google, MS and Linked in to successfully authenticate and I received an `id_token` back  but I want to be able to validate this token that I receive back from Azure but I am unsure of how to. Does the `SecurityTokenValidated` event raised mean that the token has already been validated against the `TokenValidationParameters` I defined and I do not need to validate the token? if this is the case what should I put in the `TokenValidationParameters`?

The id_token I receive back does not contain a encrypted signature to validate

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    SlidingExpiration = true,
                    LoginPath = new PathString("/"),
                    CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,


                });

            var options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {

                Authority = "https://login.windows.net/common",
                ClientId = clientId,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {

                    AuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed,
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
                    SecurityTokenReceived = OnSecurityTokenReceived,
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                    SecurityTokenValidated = OnSecurityTokenValidated,
                    MessageReceived = OnMessageReceived
                },
                Scope = "openid",
                ResponseType = "id_token",
                Description = new AuthenticationDescription
                {

                    AuthenticationType = "OpenIdConnect",
                                        },

                ConfigurationManager = new PolicyConfigurationManager(
                    string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant, "/v2.0", OidcMetadataSuffix),
                    new[] { SisuGoogle, SisuLinkedIn, SisuMicrosoft, SisuLocal, ResetPasswordLocalPolicyId }),


                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidAudiences = new string[]
                    {
                     "http://localhost:44330/",


                    },
                    IssuerSigningKey = GetSecurityKey(),
                    // If you don't add this, you get IDX10205
                    //ValidateIssuer = false,
                },
            };

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options);



 private SecurityKey GetSecurityKey()
        {
            var securityKey = "secure key";
            var signingKey = new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(securityKey));
            var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature,SecurityAlgorithms.Sha256Digest);
            return signingCredentials.SigningKey;
        }


    private Task OnSecurityTokenValidated(SecurityTokenValidatedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> arg)
            {


//do I need to validate the token here or has it already been validated??

//if I have to validate it then how do I? I've tried the following but does not work
                var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    IssuerSigningKey = GetSecurityKey()
                };

                SecurityToken validatedToken;
                var jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();


    //crashes at this point
                jwtHandler.ValidateToken(arg.ProtocolMessage.IdToken, tokenValidationParameters, out validatedToken);



                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
```

Comment: I have the same question. What did you end up doing?

Comment: @Mukus I ended up building my own validation using cryptography. I have since moved from that project. However, I belive that the callback is only raised upon successful validation of token which means that Yes, the token has been validated by the time this callback is raised. However, at the time I was unable to find any documentation to support this. The documentation may have changed now

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this sample: https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-api-dotnet.md

Or take a look at this similar question:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/893a6142-1508-4aa2-9da3-dab3b1f1a6b9/b2c-jwt-token-signature-validation?forum=WindowsAzureAD

If you use the similar configuration in the sample, then OWIN will handle the token validation with the key fetched from the metadata endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat belatedly, but the documentation for the various events can be found here:

[OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.owin.security.openidconnect.openidconnectauthenticationnotifications?view=owin-4.1)

The events you can hook into with the notifications are:

- **AuthenticationFailed**
  Invoked if exceptions are thrown during request processing. The exceptions will be re-thrown after this event unless suppressed.
- **AuthorizationCodeReceived**
  Invoked after security token validation if an authorization code is present in the protocol message.
- **MessageReceived**
  Invoked when a protocol message is first received.
- **RedirectToIdentityProvider**
  Invoked to manipulate redirects to the identity provider for SignIn, SignOut, or Challenge.
- **SecurityTokenReceived**
  Invoked with the security token that has been extracted from the protocol message.
- **SecurityTokenValidated**
  Invoked after the security token has passed validation and a ClaimsIdentity has been generated.
- **TokenResponseReceived**
  Invoked after "authorization code" is redeemed for tokens at the token endpoint.

An updated sample using some of these can be found here: [Azure AD B2C: Call an ASP.NET Web API from an ASP.NET Web App](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi).

As mentioned in the Advanced Options of [Tutorial: Add sign-in to Microsoft to an ASP.NET web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp#advanced-options) there are a number of ways that you can further restrict who can access your application once they have authenticated.